# Installation of Streamlit without Altair

Tags: python, installation, streamlit, altair

I want to use Streamlit in my organization, but my org does not allow Altair installation internally due to safety issues, but Altair is a dependency for Streamlit. Is there a way to install Streamlit without Altair?

Comment: Have your tried uninstalling it? `pip uninstall altair`

Comment: Sure, install without dependencies: `pip install --no-deps streamlit`. You can also check out [stlite](https://github.com/whitphx/stlite) to run streamlit in the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@ferdy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74657023/installation-of-streamlit-without-altair#comment131775087_74657023) and [@RJ Adriaansen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74657023/installation-of-streamlit-without-altair#comment131775164_74657023) have suggested, there are 2 ways to install streamlit without installing `altair`:

```bash
pip install streamlit && pip uninstall -y altair
```

or

```bash
pip install --no-deps streamlit
pip check | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d',' -f1 | grep -v 'altair' > requirements-no-altair.txt
pip install -r requirements-no-altair.txt
```